# MYSQL Insert a primary key in another table as foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to add a few Primary Keys from different tables as Foreign Keys to one Main table in a Query in php.

So far I got:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO m_main (M_Id, M_T_Id,  M_U_Id, M_P_Id, M_S_Id, M_Sp_Id, M_Ra_Id, M_F_Id, M_Hp, M_Rss, M_Kommentar)"
                              . "VALUES (DEFAULT, 123,  123, '".$_SESSION['sId']."' , 123, '".$_SESSION['Sp_Id']."', '".$_POST['fragestellung']."', 123,"
                              . "'".$_POST['hp']."', $rss, '".$_POST['kommentar']."')");
```

Every "123" I want to replace with an existing Primary key from other tables from my database.
How is this possible ?

Comment: A subquery might be appropriate but you've provided no information of hte table(s) containing the primary keys nor how they would relate to the record you are inserting.

Comment: @Jeeped
All of the other tables have an integer as a primary key and at least one othe column with only strings.
I just wrote "123" to check if it is possible to access / write in the database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

Something like this where `anotherTable` is the other table you want to insert from.

```
$result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO m_main (M_Id, M_T_Id,  M_U_Id, M_P_Id, M_S_Id, M_Sp_Id, M_Ra_Id, M_F_Id, M_Hp, M_Rss, M_Kommentar) "
                     . "SELECT (DEFAULT, anotherTable.id,  anotherTable.id, '".$_SESSION['sId']."' , anotherTable.id, '".$_SESSION['Sp_Id']."', '".$_POST['fragestellung']."', anotherTable.id,"
                     . "'".$_POST['hp']."', $rss, '".$_POST['kommentar']."') FROM anotherTable");
```

If needed you can also limit the number of inserted rows into `m_main` with a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I asked this question. Finally I found some time to answer it in case anybody has the same problem. Don't know why I wanted to make it so complicated. Subquerys where the answer:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO m_main (M_Id, M_T_Id,  M_U_Id, M_P_Id, M_S_Id, M_Sp_Id, M_Ra_Id, M_F_Id, M_Hp, M_Rss, M_Kommentar)"
                          . "VALUES (DEFAULT, (SELECT MAX id FROM title), (((AND SO ON...)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Where has this post been hiding for the last 3 hours?! :)